# Creating a subscribe and unsubscribe without passing the subscribers Id in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, publish-subscribe

### Overview

I'm creating a simple subscribe and unsubscribe service. I am creating it as the pattern is a simple one and we can avoid adding an addition dependency.

### Pattern

The Pattern is Simple you have an Array of Callbacks.

```
subscribers = [];
```

And three functions subscribe, unsubscribe, and publish.

```
subscribe(callback){
  //code
}
unsubscribe(){
  //code
}
publish(data){
  //code
}
```

### **Issue**

Ideally this is all the info you need, however I have yet to find a way to cleanly subscribe and unsubscribe without passing an ID of some kind to know which function to remove from the subscriber array. It would be nice to pull the function id from the caller of the subscribe function. I found there is a way to do this through [caller](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller) and [callee](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee), but they should not be used. So are there an options to capture a unique identifier from the caller of subscribe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're willing to change the pattern, you can have subscribe create an unsubscribe function which has the callback as part of its closure, and then return that function.

```
subscribe(callback) {
   subscribers.push(callback);
   return function() {
      const index = subscribers.indexOf(callback);
      if (index > -1) {
         subscribers.splice(index, 1);
      }
   };
}
//unsubscribe() {} // Doesn't exist any more on the service
publish(data) {
   //code
}
```

So when another part of your code subscribes, it will save a reference to the unsubscribe function to be used later. For example:

```
const unsubscribe = MyEventService.subscribe(function (data) {
   console.log('subscription fired!', data)
 });

// later, when this code needs to tear down
unsubscribe();
```

---

If you prefer to keep the pattern of calling into the service to unsubscribe, i see no option other than to pass in something, either an identifier, or the callback function again.

Comment: This works for me thanks you

Answer (score 1):

You could do what redux does:

Instead of having a dedicated `unsubscribe()` function, return a callback which removes the subscriber from the `subscribe()` function, i.e.:

```
let subscribers  = [];
const subscribe = subscriber => {
  subscribers.push(subscriber);
  return () => { 
    subscribers = subscribers.filter( s => s !== subscriber);
  }
}

//To subscribe
const unsubscribe = subscribe(() => doSomethingWhenEventFires());
//To unsubscribe
unsubscribe();
```

Comment: someSubscriber is a callback, not an id. I probably should have clarified that